# Grouping by similarity

Tags: clustering

I would like to find a way/algorithm to group people into, say, four groups by their answer similarity to yes/no questions.

So, each pair of people in one group would have given the same answers for a big part of the questions – (mostly) bigger than compared to people from the other three groups.

Would appreciate any pointers to the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start with the simple option: represent every person as a boolean vector in which every position represents the answer to a particular question (the length is the total number of questions). Then you can apply any standard clustering algorithm, such as [K-means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) ([hierarchical clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_clustering) would probably also work with data like this).

Comment: Thanks, will look at your two links!